# What's the advantage of `clone` over instantiating a new object in PHP?

Tags: php, object

In this code

```
<?php
$object1        = new User();
$object1->name = "Alice";
$object2        = clone $object1;
$object2->name = "Amy";

echo "object1 name = " . $object1->name . "<br>";
echo "object2 name = " . $object2->name;

class User
{
    public $name;
}
?>
```

what's the advantage of using `clone` rather than just `new`?
Is it such that we get all the same values for the attributes of `object1` in `object2` except for the `name` which we define newly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this specific situation there will be no difference. There *would* be a difference if the object had other properties (they would get reset if creating a new instance instead of cloning).

There are also other situations where `clone` can be appropriate:

- If the class of the object does not have a constructor that is accessible to you
- If the class of the object does have a constructor, but you don't know what values you should pass to it; in general, if you don't know *how* you would construct a duplicate object
- If constructing a new object has side effects that are undesirable
- If the object has internal state and you don't know how to move from a "freshly constructed" state to that of the instance you already have

Comment: Ok, that's going even beyond of what I was thinking of, especially pointing out side effects of making a second object of a type.

Comment: @TMOTTM: Actually I just thought of one more case -- although there is some overlap between them, there are quite a few.

Answer (score 2):

[`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) will copy all the property values rather than have them reset to the default. Useful if you have a query builder class, for example, and wish for two queries to be near-identical but for one or two small differences. You build the query up to the point of departure, clone it, and then use one one way and the other another.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there is none because that's an extremely poor excuse for an object.

However, imagine you are creating a game, where each class represents a type of object within the game. One such object might be a ball, that bounces along. In this case, `new Ball()` would create a new ball at the starting position, and it would bounce along following the first. However, `clone $ball1` would duplicate the current ball in its actual position.